# Multiple wildcard trigger in Azure DevOps build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a yml file which has this for the trigger:

```
trigger:
  branches:
   include: [develop, release/*]
```

however, when I make a new branch off of `develop` and call the branch "`ReleaseTest`", then commit and push code to that branch, my build isn't being triggered. Is the syntax incorrect?

My goal is to have one yml which is triggered by both commits to the develop branch and any release branch which we may make in the future, and set the appropriate build configs based on what branch it was triggered by.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is incorrect. `include: []` is not supported in azure pipeline yaml. You should define the array in azure devops yaml like below:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - release/*
    - Release/* #trigger branch is case sensitive
```

See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#push-trigger) for more information.
For read about pipelines please refer to [azure-pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#remarks).
For read about triggers please refer to [azure-pipelines-triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines).